# Vue.js SFC conditionally include template elements at compile time

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vue-cli-3

Our product has multiple customers, and each have their own customer-specific modifications.

Is there a way in a Vue2 template of an SFC to conditionally include or exclude other components at the time it's built, based on a build environment variable?

It looks like I can use something like webpack-conditional-loader to conditionally include/exclude JavaScript code at build-time, but is there an equivalent for the template code?

eg. something like this:

```
<template>
  <##if process.env === 'CustomerA'>
    <customer-a-dialog></customer-a-dialog>
  </##if>
  <##if process.env === 'CustomerB'>
    <customer-b-dialog></customer-b-dialog>
  </##if>
</template>
```

Thanks,
Spanners

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following library which can allow conditional preprocessing for html/vue template code:

[js-conditional-compile-loader](https://github.com/hzsrc/js-conditional-compile-loader)

Hope it helps!